# Gatsby-Source-Wordpress: Error when compiling. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'fields' of 'nodesType' as it is undefined

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When I go and try to run `gatsby develop` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'fields' of 'nodesType' as it is undefined.
    at generateNodeQueriesFromIngestibleFields (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/ingest-remote-schema/buil
d-queries-from-introspection/generate-queries-from-ingestable-types.js:155:13)
    at buildNodeQueries (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/ingest-remote-schema/build-queries-from-introspe
ction/build-node-queries.js:25:25)
    at runSteps (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/utils/run-steps.ts:41:9)
    at runSteps (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/utils/run-steps.ts:43:9)
    at ingestRemoteSchema (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/ingest-remote-schema/index.js:49:5)
    at runSteps (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/utils/run-steps.ts:41:9)
    at runAPI (/Users/repoFolder/Work/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:487:16)


 ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_112003 

 gatsby-source-wordpress 

        Encountered a critical error when running the buildNodeQueries build step.
        See above for more information.

not finished createSchemaCustomization - 3.831s
not finished [gatsby-source-wordpress] ingest WPGraphQL schema - 2.379s
```

I haven't made any changes, or upgraded packages and have since been working on other projects.  I tried disabling the Related Posts plugin, as well as a few others in addition to upgrading the gatsby-source-wordpress plugin.

I am configuring the plugin like in my `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
            resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
            options: {
                url: `${process.env.WPGRAPHQL_URL}`,
                verbose: false,
                develop: {
                    hardCacheData: false,
                  },
                schema: {
                    perPage: 10, // currently set to 100
                    requestConcurrency: 3, // currently set to 15
                    previewRequestConcurrency: 1, // currently set to 5
                },
                type: {
                    Page: {
                        exclude: true,
                    },
                    Menu: {
                        exclude: true,
                    },
                    MenuItem: {
                        exclude: true,
                    },
                },
                debug: {
                    graphql: {
                      onlyReportCriticalErrors: true,
                    },
                },
                searchAndReplace: [
                    {
                        search: `${process.env.GATSBY_WORDPRESS_URL_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.GATSBY_WORDPRESS_URL_PATH}`,
                        replace: `${process.env.GATSBY_SITE_URL_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.GATSBY_SITE_URL_PATH}`,
                    },
                ],
                html: {
                    useGatsbyImage: true,
                },
            },
        },
```

`and I am configuring the plugin / constructing the node in`gatsby-node.js`like the following:`

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions

    const BlogPostTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/BlogPost.tsx")
    const BlogTagPostsTemplate = path.resolve(
        "./src/templates/BlogTagPosts.tsx"
    )
    const BlogCategoryPostsTemplate = path.resolve(
        "./src/templates/BlogCategoryPosts.tsx"
    )

    const BlogPostsResult = await graphql(`
        {
            allWpPost {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        slug
                        uri
                        link
                        title
                        excerpt
                        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
                        modified(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
                        author {
                            node {
                                avatar {
                                    url
                                }
                                id
                                name
                                uri
                                slug
                            }
                        }
                        featuredImage {
                            node {
                                localFile {
                                    childImageSharp {
                                        gatsbyImageData(
                                            width: 1920
                                            placeholder: BLURRED
                                            formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        categories {
                            nodes {
                                id
                                count
                                name
                                slug
                            }
                        }
                        tags {
                            nodes {
                                id
                                count
                                name
                                slug
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    if (BlogPostsResult.errors) {
        reporter.panicOnBuild("Error while running GraphQL query.")
        return
    }

    const BlogPosts = BlogPostsResult.data.allWpPost.edges

    BlogPosts.forEach((post, index) => {
        const date = post.node.date
        createPage({
            path: `/${post.node.categories.nodes[0].slug}/${moment(date).format(
                "YYYY"
            )}/${moment(date).format("MM")}/${post.node.slug}.html`,
            component: BlogPostTemplate,
            context: {
                id: post.node.id,
                slug: post.node.slug,
                uri: post.node.uri,
                previous: index === 0 ? null : BlogPosts[index - 1].node,
                next:
                    index === BlogPosts.length - 1
                        ? null
                        : BlogPosts[index + 1].node,
            },
        })
    })

    createPaginatedPages({
        edges: BlogPosts,
        createPage: createPage,
        pageTemplate: "src/templates/BlogPosts.tsx",
        pageLength: 10,
        pathPrefix: "blog",
    })

    const BlogTagPosts = new Map()
    const BlogCategoryPosts = new Map()

    BlogPosts.forEach((post) => {
        const tags = post.node.tags.nodes
        if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
            tags.forEach((tag) => {
                if (BlogTagPosts.has(tag.slug)) {
                    BlogTagPosts.set(tag.slug, [
                        ...BlogTagPosts.get(tag.slug),
                        post,
                    ])
                } else {
                    BlogTagPosts.set(tag.slug, [post])
                }
                if (BlogTagPosts.has(tag.title)) {
                    BlogTagPosts.set(tag.title, [
                        ...BlogTagPosts.get(tag.title),
                        post,
                    ])
                } else {
                    BlogTagPosts.set(tag.title, [post])
                }
            })
        }
        const categories = post.node.categories.nodes
        if (categories && categories.length > 0) {
            categories.forEach((category) => {
                if (BlogCategoryPosts.has(category.slug)) {
                    BlogCategoryPosts.set(category.slug, [
                        ...BlogCategoryPosts.get(category.slug),
                        post,
                    ])
                } else {
                    BlogCategoryPosts.set(category.slug, [post])
                }
                if (BlogCategoryPosts.has(category.title)) {
                    BlogCategoryPosts.set(category.title, [
                        ...BlogCategoryPosts.get(category.title),
                        post,
                    ])
                } else {
                    BlogCategoryPosts.set(category.title, [post])
                }
            })
        }
    })

    const BlogTagSlugs = [...BlogTagPosts.keys()]
    const BlogCategorySlugs = [...BlogCategoryPosts.keys()]
    //const BlogCategoryTitles = [...BlogCategoryPosts.keys()];

    if (BlogTagSlugs.length > 0) {
        BlogTagSlugs.forEach((BlogTagSlug) => {
            createPage({
                path: `/tag/${BlogTagSlug}`,
                component: BlogTagPostsTemplate,
                context: {
                    group: BlogTagPosts.get(BlogTagSlug),
                    slug: BlogTagSlug,
                    title: BlogTagPosts.get("tag.title"),
                },
            })
        })
    }

    if (BlogCategorySlugs.length > 0) {
        BlogCategorySlugs.forEach((BlogCategorySlug) => {
            createPage({
                path: `/category/${BlogCategorySlug}`,
                component: BlogCategoryPostsTemplate,
                context: {
                    group: BlogCategoryPosts.get(BlogCategorySlug),
                    slug: BlogCategorySlug,
                    title: BlogCategoryPosts.get("category.title"),
                },
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Where do I start?

I have tried upgrading packages, stripping out the config option in the config file, and deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstalling the packages. I do run into errors when trying a normal `npm i` command, but that is fixed by adding the flag `-legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: I have exactly this - not changed anything, but its not working. I wonder if there's been an automatic upgrade to the wp-graphql in wordpress or something similar. I'm on 
    "gatsby": "^4.7.1",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^6.7.0"

Comment: It is definitely Wordpress / plugin specific. I redownloaded a couple other boilerplates using the gatsby-source-wordpress plugin, simply changed the GraphQL endpoint and still got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this same error, but I got this after upgrading my WordPress plugins. Im pretty sure this is due to the new version 13.x of WP GraphQL. You can fix this by downgrading the WP GraphQL WordPress plugin to version 12.3. You can grab that [v12 version here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-graphql/advanced/). Also more info on this issue and if a fix is implemented it will probably be updated [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/37114).

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue.
Downgrading WP GraphQL to version 1.12.3 fixed this for me.
Here's the link [wp-graphql.1.12.3](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-graphql.1.12.3.zip)